# Estimate Posterior with: Binomial Likelihood with 1/θ Prior

Tags: self-study, binomial-distribution, prior, posterior, beta-distribution

I am trying to estimate the posterior distribution using Bayes theorem. The following information is given:

\begin{align}
\newcommand{\prior}{{\rm prior}}
\newcommand{\likelihood }{{\rm likelihood }}
\newcommand{\posterior}{{\rm posterior}}
\posterior&∝\likelihood \times \prior  \\
\likelihood(x|θ)&∝ θ^k\times(1-θ)^{n-k}  \\
\prior(θ)&∝1/θ
\end{align}

Here I interested in estimating the posterior distribution of θ, with Binomial likelihood(k successes of the n trials).

By multiplying the likelihood and prior I get the following:

\begin{align}
\posterior&∝θ^k\times(1-θ)^{n-k}\times1/θ \quad = \quad θ^k\times(1-θ)^{n-k}\timesθ^{-1}   \\
\posterior&∝θ^{k-1}\times(1-θ)^{n-k} 
\end{align}

**Question:**
The posterior distribution looks like Beta distribution: $θ^{\alpha-1}(1-θ)^{\beta-1}$. It is quite clear that $\alpha=k$ , but I am struggling to figure out how to transform power $n-k$ to look like $\beta_{new}={\rm something} - 1$. Could anyone point me to the right direction?

Comment: Is your data discrete or continuous? Is the parameter a proportion.  I am thinking you may be talking about a situation wher you have a beta posterior and a binomial likelihood.  But why does a 1/theta  prior enter into it? Is that even a proper prior?

Comment: $\beta = n-k+1$.

Comment: This prior should not be used because the posterior is not defined when $X=n$, which has a positive probability to occur under the Binomial model.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, the data is discrete. The random variable is the numer of patience with no side effects. I am a bit comfused myself about the form of the prior, but that was given by the assignment: p(theta) ∝ 1/theta.

Comment: @Xi'an indeed it looks wierd, but that was given by the assignment: p(theta) ∝ 1/theta

Comment: @whuber Can you explain your hint without giving away the answer (assuming that you know it)?

Comment: If this is an assignement, you should have included the  `self-study` tag.

Comment: This thread has the `[self-study]` tag, & does present what the OP understands thus far. It meets our standards & can remain open.

Comment: @Michael That wasn't a hint: it is the answer.  This is a trivial question.

Comment: So you get the beta posterior. Was it legitimate to use i/theta as a prior? The exponents are then k-1 and n-k?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't the prior, $p(\theta) \propto \theta^{-1}$ merely a $\mbox{beta}(a=0,b=1)$ distribution? (If $a=0$ is uncomfortable, then set $a=\epsilon$ for small $\epsilon$.) Therefore the usual beta-Bernoulli update rule should apply. That is, with a Bernoulli likelihood function (which this is, for $N$ independent trials), and a conjugate beta prior (for which the present problem is a special case), the posterior is again a beta distribution: $\mbox{beta}(a+k,b+N-k)$. Here we start with $a=\epsilon$ and $b=1$, so the posterior is $\mbox{beta}(\epsilon+k,1+N-k)$.

P.S. For a derivation of the general beta-Bernoulli update rule, see p. 132 of [DBDA2E](https://sites.google.com/site/doingbayesiandataanalysis/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I had the same in mind, but somehow Alpha=0 did not make sense as by definition of Beta distribution Alpha>0. Would that be a case of an improper prior? Also, would the posterior still be a proper Beta distribution?

Comment: @Artur check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#Haldane.27s_prior_probability_.28Beta.280.2C0.29.29

Comment: @Artur: as indicated in my earlier comment, you cannot use this improper prior because the posterior is not defined when $X=n$.